#  The Other Shira for Moshe

Tags: riddle

Who, besides בני ישראל , sang the שירה of אז ישיר משה?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sefer Shmuel after the Plishttim stole the Ahron Kopdesh and it caused them Much grief. They sent the Ahron Kodesh Back with Cows they where singing Shira to Hashem according to one opinion in the gemara in Avodah Zara according too רבי מאיר  the song they sang was Az Yashir Moshe Ubnei Yisroel

Answer (score 2):

The Levi'im in the Beis Hamikdash sang the first half of this shirah one week, and the second half the next week, on Shabbos afternoon while the korban tamid was being offered. (The third week, they would sing the Song of the Well - Num. 21:17ff.)

(Rosh Hashanah 31a)